# Getting question mark symbol with in the body content in mail using java

Tags: java, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I am using Javax mail for reading mail content and will store into database. But when i am reading mail content using java there is question mark found with in the content.

```
Dear S?ir,
```

Like this. I have used below code.

```
        Folder folder1 = store.getFolder("INBOX");
              if(!folder1.isOpen()) 
              folder1.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

              Message[] message = folder1.getMessages();              
 Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
 for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
               MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
               String content = part.getContent().toString(); 
               result = new String (content.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
  }
```

But no luck. How can i remove this question mark?

Comment: I have used String buffer instead of string. Please use that , it worked for me.

Comment: How ? please share the code

Comment: Sorry... still same issue

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Hi Below code will might help you. I have used buffer instead of String.

Below is the code. 
// Email Message

```
StringBuffer strMessage = new StringBuffer();
strMessage.append("Thank you for your Request . Your One time password  is: "+ otp + ". "); 
strMessage.append("\n\n");
strMessage.append("Best Regards");
strMessage.append("\n\n");
strMessage.append("COMPANY NAME");
sendemailinput.setStatus("0");
sendemailinput.setSendType("HTML");
```

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: java  -Dfile.encoding='UTF-8' -jar mail.jar